# WPF Stretch Middle Content in DockPanel or Stackpanel

Tags: wpf, vb.net

How do I stretch the content in the middle section of a `Stackpanel` or `Dockpanel`.  I know that a dockpanel will stretch the last item but I need to stretch the middle item.  I know that I could use a grid with `*` for the middle section but I want to be able to set the left and/or right items as collapsed depending on my window size.

Answer (score 0):

You should still use a DockPanel with `LastChildFill` setted. 
Your DockPanel will stretch the last element you put in it, not the last one according to view.
So you can put the element you want to stretch in the last position and use `DockPanel.Dock="Top/Bottom/Right/Left"` on others one.